# Meeting three times a week

Tags: probability

I did this small exercise, and I wanted to confirm that it's correct.

A friend and I go to the gym (k=)3 times a week. What are the chances that we meet on all (k=)3 days?

Answer (matlab): nchoosek(7,3) / nchoosek(7,3)^2 = 0.0571

$= \frac{1}{\left({7\atop 3}\right)}$

What about k=4? The same probability.

---

EDIT: I removed the division by 2 as suggested.
Initially, I divided the denominator by 2! to unorder the pair selection. However, it is ordered: selecting Mon-Wed for me and Thu-Sat for my friend isn't the same as swapping the selections.

Comment: Please try writing your maths formulas using [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)

Comment: Why the divided by $2$?

Comment: Dividing by 2 because it's unordered.

Comment: but $\binom{n}{k}$ is unordered already

Comment: For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Zohar Levi, firstly I presume that your friend and you are deciding the gym days for  each week independently and uniformly at random. (Details like this need to be put into a question for it to be meaningful)

Then for this week, your friend has decided, say, Mon, Tues, Fri as gym days, you can match it in only one way out of the $\binom73$ options you have,

Thus P(you meet all three days) $= \Large\frac{ 1} {\binom73} = \frac{1}{35}$

And similarly for meeting $4$ days in a week, $Pr =   \Large\frac{ 1} {\binom74} = \frac{1}{35}$

The division by $2$ is incorrect.

Answer (score -2):

It would be better if you wrote using LaTex code, since it is more visible. To continue with your question, I think it is right. In the case of $k=4$, it would be the same but with $7\choose{4}$ in the formula.